# why time input filed expecting to be a date in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have stored time using $filter('date')($scope.booktime, 'mediumTime') while booking.after booking i have editbooking function is there when i pass time i am getting error in console Error: [ngModel:datefmt] Expected `11:59:00 AM` to be a date how can i solve this im trying sice 3days i am not able to solve this error.i want to pass  11:59:00 AM to time input field

```js
function HistoryCtrl($scope, $filter) {

     
         
         $scope.booktime = "11:59:00 AM";
    
}
```

```html
<div ng-app ng-controller="HistoryCtrl">
    
     <div class="col">
            <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
            <span class="input-label" >Time</span>
            <input type="time" ng-model="booktime" name="booktime" min="09:00:00" max="21:00:00" required="">
            </label>
            <div class="form-error" ng-messages="projectForm.booktime.$error">
               <div class="form-error" ng-message="required">* Mandatory</div>
               <div class="form-error" ng-message="min">Booking times: 9am - 9 pm</div>
               <div class="form-error" ng-message="max">Booking times: 9am - 9 pm</div>
            </div>
         </div>
   
    
   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to correctly format it, use the date filter (or remove the "AM" from your string):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/nz8934L9/1/)

```
app.controller('controller', ['$scope', '$filter', function ($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.booktime = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'HH:mm')
}]);
```

Comment: how can i pass this 11:59:00 AM

Comment: Don't use type=time if you wanna add AM/PM or use this directive https://github.com/phng/angular-input-time